# Maya , render layers, and instances in Python 2.7

Tags: python, maya

I have several render layers with different random names. Each render layer has a lights instance in it. I need to remove this instance.

[image: Screengrab to show the instance]

This is as far as I've got:

```
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.override as override
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.selector as selector
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.collection as collection
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderLayer as renderLayer
from maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderSetup import instance

import maya.cmds as cmds

rs = instance()

#this creates a render layer called MyRenderSetupLayer
rl = rs.createRenderLayer("MyRenderSetupLayer")

#This creates a lights collection instance inside the created render layer
l1 = rl.lightsCollectionInstance()

#deletes the lights collection instance in the render layer
collection.delete(l1)
```

The last line is the one that deletes the lights instance in the created render layer, so I know you can do it. My issue is that I don't know how to assign a variable (like l1) to an existing lights collection instance so I can then delete it.

If I try and see what type is l1, I get

> <class 'maya.app.renderSetup.model.collection.LightsCollection'>

I have always different names in my render layers, but even if I did, I can't figure out how to delete those instances, unless I created them in that script, as they are assigned to a variable and then I can just delete it like that. But since these files were created by different people, my current workflow doesn't work.

Thanks so much! I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I've sorted it out. You need to treat the lights instance as a collection. Although, the name of the collection won't be `lights`, as it shows in the render layer like this:

[image: Lights Instance collection]

By default, these instances will be named `lightsCollection`, `lightsCollection1`, `lightsCollection2`, and so forth.

You can find these instances in the outliner to make sure you know what's the name you're after, but you must first disable the "show DAG objects only" and then in the render setup menu, you'll need to enable "Display render setup nodes in editors" as they are hidden by default.

Don't just delete these nodes though as it may cause issues in your scene.
If anybody wants more info let me know and I'll post more information.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I'm quite new to render setup. Couldn't yuo simply list all children of your renderlayer and check if one of them is a lightcollection and if yes, delete it?